# SQL Server Getting First & Last Row that makes up aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Table that stores data on price movement over a minute. Each record contains the last Minute's Open, High, Low, Close & Volume

```
CREATE TABLE TimeBar (
  Instrument varchar(20),
  BarTimeStamp datetimeoffset(7),
  Open decimal(18, 5),
  High decimal(18, 5),
  Low decimal(18, 5),
  Close decimal(18, 5),
  Volume int
)
```

What I am trying to do is create a query where I can aggregate the data into higher time frames, for example I want to be able to Show the Open, High, Low & Close for each Hour.

Below is my query so far, I have managed to get the High and The Low, but how do you get the  Open and The Close?

```
  SELECT MIN(BarTimeStamp) AS TimeStamp,
         MAX(High) AS High,
         MIN(Low) AS Low,
         SUM(Volume) AS Volume
    FROM TimeBar
   WHERE Instrument = 'XYZ'
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, BarTimeStamp), DATEPART(MONTH, BarTimeStamp), DATEPART(DAY, BarTimeStamp), DATEPART(HOUR, BarTimeStamp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the main query as a subquery, taken for each record the min timestamp and max timestamp, and so, take the respective open and close prices for them.

```
SELECT x.*, TI.Open, TE.Close
FROM
(
SELECT   Instrument,
         MIN(BarTimeStamp) AS TimeStampIni,
         MAX(BarTimeStamp) AS TimeStampEnd,
         MAX(High) AS High,
         MIN(Low) AS Low,
         SUM(Volume) AS Volume
    FROM TimeBar
GROUP BY Instrument, DATEPART(YEAR, BarTimeStamp), DATEPART(MONTH, BarTimeStamp), DATEPART(DAY, BarTimeStamp), DATEPART(HOUR, BarTimeStamp)
) x
inner join TimeBar TI on ti.Instrument = x.Instrument AND TI.BarTimeStamp = x.TimeStampIni
inner join TimeBar Te on te.Instrument = x.Instrument AND Te.BarTimeStamp = x.TimeStampEnd
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is group by the time ranges:

```
SELECT MIN(BarTimeStamp) AS StartTimeStamp,
         MAX(BarTimeStamp) AS EndTimeStamp
    FROM #TimeBar
   WHERE Instrument = 'TEST'
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, BarTimeStamp), DATEPART(MONTH, BarTimeStamp), DATEPART(DAY,       BarTimeStamp), DATEPART(HOUR, BarTimeStamp)
```

After that, it's a matter of:

- doing a join to get the ranges,
- doing a join to get the start
- doing a join to get the min
- grouping by the original range to select everything

I like to use common table expressions to make it easier:

```
;WITH times as (
    SELECT MIN(BarTimeStamp) AS StartTimeStamp,
             MAX(BarTimeStamp) AS EndTimeStamp
        FROM #TimeBar
       WHERE Instrument = 'TEST'
    GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, BarTimeStamp), DATEPART(MONTH, BarTimeStamp), DATEPART(DAY, BarTimeStamp), DATEPART(HOUR, BarTimeStamp)
)
SELECT 
    StartTimeStamp as TimeStamp
    ,MIN([first].[Open]) as [Open]
    ,MAX(ranged.High) as High
    ,MAX(ranged.Low) as Low
    ,MIN([last].[Close]) as [Close]
    ,SUM(ranged.Volume) as Volume
FROM times 
INNER JOIN #TimeBar ranged ON times.StartTimeStamp <= ranged.BarTimeStamp AND times.EndTimeStamp >= ranged.BarTimeStamp
INNER JOIN #TimeBar [first] ON times.StartTimeStamp = [first].BarTimeStamp 
INNER JOIN #TimeBar [last] ON times.EndTimeStamp = [last].BarTimeStamp 
GROUP BY [times].StartTimeStamp
```

Here's my test data:

```
CREATE TABLE #TimeBar (
  Instrument varchar(20),
  BarTimeStamp datetimeoffset(7),
  [Open] decimal(18, 5),
  High decimal(18, 5),
  Low decimal(18, 5),
  [Close] decimal(18, 5),
  Volume int
)

insert into #TimeBar values ('TEST', '2011-11-21 1:00', 5, 6, 4, 8, 100)
insert into #TimeBar values ('TEST', '2011-11-21 1:10', 1, 7, 3, 4, 100)
insert into #TimeBar values ('TEST', '2011-11-21 2:10', 15, 16, 17, 18, 100)
insert into #TimeBar values ('TEST', '2011-11-21 2:30', 12, 16, 17, 19, 100)
insert into #TimeBar values ('TEST', '2011-11-21 2:50', 13, 14, 15, 20, 100)
```

and the result is:

```
TimeStamp                          Open                                    High                                    Low                                     Close                                   Volume
---------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- -----------
2011-11-21 01:00:00.0000000 +00:00 5.00000                                 7.00000                                 4.00000                                 4.00000                                 200
2011-11-21 02:10:00.0000000 +00:00 15.00000                                16.00000                                17.00000                                20.00000                                300
```

Note, I used a temp table for this, just change #TimeBar to TimeBar to change it for your real table.

---

Aside, I don't like to see `Instrurment varchar` as a field definition. You should be using a [surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) for this.